# Modify elements in Nested Repeaters QML

Tags: qt, qml, pyside

I have added a minimal reproducible example for this question in relation to the last one I asked. I am using Python, Pyside6, and QML to create my application. I am trying to customize the amount of overall widgets created, as well as the custom components inside them. I am using a nested Repeater that you can see in `widget.qml`. I am able to use the outer repeater to instantiate 3 header elements; however, I am unable to control how many `BasicContainer` elements are created. Each header element should correspond with just 5 `BasicComponents` that get instantiated based off the length of one of the widget components, like `item1Components` in the main.py. Just like how the header widgets get instantiated, the model appends a row for each dictionary element that appears in a list I pass in.

For instance, under the first header element, you would see the list: widget1random, widget1random2, etc... under the second header element to the right: widget2random, widget2random2, etc...

In the current state, all 15 components get attached to each header widget which is not what I am trying to accomplish.

main.py

```
import os
import sys

from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.path[0]), ".."))

from PySide6.QtCore import Property, QUrl, QObject, Qt, QCoreApplication
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide6.QtQuick import QQuickView

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

# QstandardItem roles
SetText = Qt.UserRole+1

class ControlledSignalWidget(QObject):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._model = QStandardItemModel()
        self._model.setItemRoleNames({Qt.DisplayRole: b"display"})
        self._setpoints = QStandardItemModel()
        self._setpoints.setItemRoleNames({SetText: b"textField"})
        
    @Property(QObject, constant=True)
    def model(self):
        return self._model
     
    @Property(QObject, constant=True)
    def setpoints(self):
        return self._setpoints
            
    #create custom number of widgets
    def create_widgets(self, widgets, allComponents):
        counter = 1
        # Iterates for the amount of widgets created
        for general, widget in widgets.items():
        #for key in widget:
            print("Adding new widget")
            item = QStandardItem(widget["Header"])  
            self._model.appendRow(item)
            self.create_setpoints(allComponents["item" + str(counter)+"Components"])
            print("Added widget")
            counter +=1
    
    def create_setpoints(self, component):
        for subWidget in component:
            print(subWidget)
            item = QStandardItem()  
            item.setData(subWidget["title"], SetText)  
            self._setpoints.appendRow(item)
         
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    
    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeViewToRootObject)
    
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "widget.qml"))

    def handle_status_changed(status):
        if status == QQuickView.Error:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)
    
    widgets = {'widget1':{'Header': "Header Text"},
                'widget2':{'Header': "Header Text"}}
    
    item1Components = [{'title': "widget1random"},
                        {'title': "widget1random2"}]
    
    item2Components = [{'title': "widget2random"},
                        {'title': "widget2random2"}]
    

    allComponents = {'item1Components': item1Components, 'item2Components': item2Components}
    
    mainWidget = ControlledSignalWidget()
    mainWidget.create_widgets(widgets, allComponents)
    
    view.rootContext().setContextProperty("mainWidget", mainWidget)
    
    view.statusChanged.connect(handle_status_changed, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
    view.setSource(url)
    view.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

widget.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item {
    id: root
    width: 1000
    height: 800
    
    GridLayout{
        columns: 3
        
        Repeater{
            id: repeater1
            model: mainWidget.model
                ColumnLayout{
                    Header{
                        title: model.display
                    }
                    
                    Repeater{
                        id: repeater2
                        model: mainWidget.setpoints
                        ColumnLayout{
                            BasicContainer{
                                mainText: model.textField
                            }
                        }
                    }   
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Header.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

Item {
    id: header
    width: 300
    height: 30
    x: 177
    y: 219

    property alias title: widgetHeader.text

    Rectangle {
        id: boxRect
        x: 193
        y: 224
        width: 408
        height: 39
        color: "#aaaaaa"
        anchors.fill: parent
        
            Text {
                id: widgetHeader
                color: "#ffffff"
                text: "Default text"
                font.pixelSize: 20
                font.family: "Roboto"
                textFormat: Text.AutoText
            }
    }
}
```

BasicContainer.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 30
    visible: true

    property alias mainText: textItem1.text

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        width: parent.width

        Text {
            id: textItem1
            text: qsTr("Default Title")
            font.pixelSize: 14
            font.family: "Roboto"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ... _minimal_ ...

Comment: @folibis Hi, sorry, I minimized some of the code especially in the QML that aren't really relevant, and cut some from the main too. I think what is on here now is hopefully all the code I need to illustrate my point

Comment: You have 2 models, `mainWidget.model`, and `mainWidget.setpoints`, the problem is that `setpoints` contains all instances. You need to re-work your data structure -  you should use one model, which in turn contains a nested unique internal `setpoints` model for each header - each of these should contain only the entries that is relevant to that header.

Comment: @fallerd I see what you are saying, but after researching for a while, it seems that the only way I can accomplish that is through implementing a tree from `QAbstractItemModel` to be able to use some sort of special nested models? Seems like a lot of work since there isn't pre-written Python implementations for `QAbstractItemModel` that I can borrow but it seems like writing my own is my only option right now

Comment: I don't use PySide, so I have no recommendations there. However, nested `ListModel`s are built into QML, though poorly documented. So if you push your data to the QML side, you can do this much more simply. For a simple dynamic example, create a `ListModel`, and populate with: `yourModel.append({innerList:[{innerListItem: 6}]})` - you can retrieve this data with: `yourModel.get(0).innerList.get(0).innerListItem` In your example, you would set `innerList` as the model for `repeater2`.